# Laravel one to many results empty after inserts

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-8

I have this relationship:

```
class UserWeek extends BaseModel
{
    public function userDays()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(UserDay::class, 'week_id');
    }
}
```

I have this method inside my model:

```
public function days($userWeek)
{
    if ($userWeek->userDays->count() == 0) {
        $date = $this->start;
        $carbon = Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d', $date);
        while ($date <= $this->end) {
            UserDay::insert([
                'week_id' => $userWeek->id,
                'date' => $date,
            ]);
            $date = $carbon->addDay()->format('Y-m-d');
        }
    }
    return $userWeek->userDays;
}
```

This method is supposed to return the days which belongs to a week.

BUT at the first time, there will be no days, so it will create them.

I check the database after execution of this method, days are really created.

STRANGELY this method returns an empty collection, which is the initial content of `$userWeek->userDays`

I think I understand the cause here, `$userWeek->userDays` seems to be kind of cached when I call it first. YET I don't have the solution to this problem.

I would appreciate a clean explanation and solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're correct

```
if ($userWeek->userDays->count() == 0)
```

In there you load the relation and then `count()`, so this `$userWeek->userDays` will be a collection. That way of querying is call [*lazy/dynamic* loading](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#relationship-methods-vs-dynamic-properties) in laravel's doc.

1. You can get the `count` from a query instead of the collection.

```
if ($userWeek->userDays()->count() == 0)
```

The idea on this one is that all types of eloquent relationships serve as queries ([Querying Relations](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#querying-relations)).

2. Reload the collection

```
$userWeek->load('userDays');
return $userWeek->userDays;
```

3. Return a fresh call of the relationship

```
return $userWeek->userDays()->get();
```

Comment: I thought about the first option but I didn't want to do that. Second option seems nice and it worked. If you could share the doc about it (if there is) that would be nice too.